# How to split a comma delimited string of numbers into Oracle NUMBER_ARRAY

Tags: arrays, oracle

How to split a comma delimited string of numbers into DBMS_UTILITY.NUMBER_ARRAY?

```
SET serveroutput on;

declare
l_tablen  BINARY_INTEGER;
l_tab     DBMS_UTILITY.NUMBER_ARRAY;

begin

DBMS_UTILITY.comma_to_table ('1,2,3', l_tablen, l_tab);

FOR i IN 1 .. l_tablen LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(i || ' : ' || l_tab(i));
END LOOP;

end;
```

This of course gives us

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'COMMA_TO_TABLE'
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of your variable l_tab should be DBMS_UTILITY.UNCL_ARRAY and not DBMS_UTILITY.NUMBER_ARRAY. Cheers